# Mint Linux GPT to MBR

Tags: linux, bios, linux-mint, mbr, gpt

I am currently running Mint Linux on a PC with an old Intel Motherboard. It works just fine but I have have to select the HDD as the boot device manually upon start-up every time because the BIOS claims not to be able to find a OS if left to find it on its own. After a lot of searching I have determined that this is most likely caused by the old BIOS not working with GPT correctly. I would like know what would be the simplest way to change this without having to reformat the drive and reinstall the entire OS because that will mean a lot of software downloads on slow internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be ways to get your system to boot without doing that conversion. See [this page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/bios.html) of the GPT fdisk documentation for some suggestions. The single most likely-to-work option is to add a "boot/active" flag to the 0xEE partition in the protective MBR. Mint's `fdisk` should be able to do this by using the `a` option in its main menu. If you try this and it doesn't work, you can go ahead with the GPT-to-MBR conversion with `gdisk`, as grawity suggests.

To answer the questions you posed in a comment to grawity's answer, you can do a GPT-to-MBR conversion from a regular boot; but you should reboot right after doing the conversion. To re-install GRUB, though, you'll need an emergency boot system. Running [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is one relatively easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [*gptfdisk*](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html#gpt2mbr):

```
# gdisk /dev/sda
Command: r (recovery and transformation options)
Recovery command: g (convert GPT into MBR and exit)
```

Now reinstall grub or another MBR-compatible bootloader.

Note that converting tables with more than 4 partitions can be problematic, if there's not enough space for the extended/logical partition entries.

Comment: Can I do this from my running system or do a need a live stick? Also, how should I reinstall grub Lastly? I only have 3 partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest (but ugly) way would be to insert another bootable device and chain from there to the disk.

E.g. a small USB pendrive with GRUB[2] or LILO on it.
Then let the PC boot from the pendrive.

Ugly though. I hope someone posts a better answer, but in a pinch this should work.

Comment: That does seem a bit too ugly. I would prefer not having to keep a USB drive there...

Comment: Agreed. If you need an emergency solution *right now* then it works. But it feels as a temporarily kludge.  Anyway, the day is fresh, lets see how many answers arrive before the day is over.

Comment: And grawity saves the day. :)